# How to correctly import modules on engines in Jupyter Notebook for parallel processing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipython-parallel

I wish to run an embarrassingly parallel function that creates plots (and eventually will save them to a file) using Jupyter Notebook with Python (edit - I found a much simpler way to do exactly this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871376/how-to-run-an-ipython-notebook-in-parallel-just-changing-some-parameter-values/21339644#21339644)). I'm trying the simplest version possible and I'm getting an import error.

Where and why should I import the relevant modules? I think I'm importing them everywhere just to be sure but still I have an error!

The positions in the files for the imports are numbered from 1-4

[1] Is this line really necessary? why?

[2] Is this line really necessary? why?

[3] Is this line really necessary? why?

[4] Is this line really necessary? why?

Below are my files:
The jupyter notebook file:

```
import ipyparallel
clients = ipyparallel.Client()
print(clients.ids)
dview = clients[:]
with dview.sync_imports():
    import module #[1]
    import matplotlib #[2]
import module #[3]
dview.map_sync(module.pll, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

and a python file name module.py

```
import matplotlib #[4]
def pll(x):
    matplotlib.pyplot.plot(x, '.')
```

When I run the notebook I get the following output

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
importing module on engine(s)
importing matplotlib on engine(s)
[Engine Exception]
NameErrorTraceback (most recent call last)<string> in <module>()
(...)
NameError: name 'matplotlib' is not defined
```

Comment: Are the engines running locally or on another system?

Comment: @frmdstryr locally! All in the same computer

Comment: Does it work if you move import #4 into the pll function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Short answer

sync_imports is unnecessary when you use module functions. This should be sufficient:

```
# notebook:
import ipyparallel as ipp
client = ipp.Client()
dview = client[:]

import module
dview.map_sync(module.pll, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

and

```
# module.py
from matplotlib import pyplot
def pll(x):
    pyplot.plot(x, '.')
```

One caveat: You will almost certainly want to setup matplotlib to use a non-default backend on the engines. **You must do this before importing pyplot**. The two logical choices with ipython parallel are `agg` if you are just saving to files, or `%matplotlib inline` if you want to see plots interactively in the notebook. To use agg:

```
import matplotlib
dview.apply_sync(matplotlib.use, 'agg')
```

or setup inline plotting:

```
%px %matplotlib inline
```

## Long answer

To answer your bulleted questions:

- [1] no, unless you want `module` defined in the globals everywhere
- [2] no, unless you want `matplotlib` defined in the globals everywhere
- [3] yes, this is needed to pass `.pll` to map
- [4] yes, because `module` is a different namespace from `__main__`, which is where all of your notebook code is running.

There are two contexts you need to think about when dealing with what needs to be imported and where:

### interactively defined functions

When a function is defined *interactively* (that is, the `def foo()` is in your notebook), name lookup is performed in the interactive namespace, and the interactive namespace on your engines *may differ* between the engines and client. For instance, you can see this with:

```
import numpy
%px numpy = 'whywouldyoudothis'

def return_numpy():
    return numpy # resolved locally *on engines*
dview.apply_sync(return_numpy)
```

where the `apply` will return a list of ['why..'] strings, not your local `numpy` import. Python doesn't know that names refer to modules or anything else; it's all a matter of what namespace(s) are used for looking up the names. This is why you will often see interactively defined functions that look like one of these:

```
import module
%px import module
def foo():
    return module.x
```

or this:

```
def foo():
    import module
    return module.x
```

Both are ways to ensure that `module` in `foo` maps to the imported module on the engines: one performs an interactive-namespace import everywhere and relies on global-namespace lookup. The other imports in the function, so it can't be wrong.

`sync_imports()` is a pure-Python way to do the same thing as:

```
import module
%px import module
```

It imports the module both here and there. If you use `sync_imports`, it is unnecessary to repeat the import locally as well, as the local import has already been performed.

### module functions

If the function is defined in a module, as yours is, it will find globals in its module, not in the interactive namespace. So `import matplotlib` in your notebook has no effect on whether the `matplotlib` name is defined when `module.pll` is called. Similarly, importing matplotlib in the module does not make it available in the interactive namespace.

Something important to consider: when you send a module function to the engines, it only sends a *reference* to the function, not the *content* of the function or module. So if `from module import pll` returns something different on the engines from the client, you will get different behavior. This can trip people up when working with *local* modules in ipython parallel while actively changing that module. Reloading that module in the notebook **does not** reload the module on the engines. It's going to send the same `module.pll` reference. So if you are actively working on `module.py`, you are going to need to call `reload(module)` *everywhere* when that module changes.

Comment: Extremely helpful and also pedagogic! Thank you!